# pandas does not encode my csv file when reading it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a problem in the encoding when reading my csv file.
I tried several encoding utf8, latin1,...
but nothing has changed.
here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/L540/Desktop/data.csv",encoding='utf8')

df.info()
```

and here is a capture of my dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbrxc.png)

Comment: What exactly did you get and what did you expect? Give a specific example.

Comment: I received my dataframe in object type and I am waiting for a sting because I have special characters . In the attached image. there is the description of the attributes for example Brand name is in object but I view it in string (ps : brand name contains special characters)

Comment: What you said is not even remotely specific.

Comment: do you mean string?  string is `object` dtype in pandas.  Unless you are asking about "my dataframe shows "\x4a" and not decoding my special characters correctly.", you are getting what you expect to get.

Comment: @DYZ  I want my attributes to be the same in the csv file because with object it is a problem for me in their analyzes.
this is why I used the encoding to avoid that it is a problem of coding but when I used `encoding='utf8'`  nothing changed my attributes remained the same object type.

Comment: I have no problem with encoding
it is when I analyze these attributes with plot there is the code 
`df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(10, 12))`
it does not display them in the plot that's why I thought that type object has a problem with plot

Comment: @Emma the link in this photo shows that attributes of type int or float eg RepportId or DIN are displayed with subplots but attributes of type object are not displayed

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJZz6.png